# Convert dataframe into factor in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
>df1
df1
barcode                     cell.subset$Cluster
N106.LPB.AAACCTGAGCAGACTG        CD4+ Activated
N106.LPB.AAAGATGTCAGATAAG                 Tregs
N106.LPB.AAAGTAGGTCTAAAGA        CD4+ Activated
N106.LPB.AACCATGGTACATGTC        CD4+ Activated

>factor1
N106.LPB.AAACCTGAGCAGACTG N106.LPB.AAAGATGTCAGATAAG N106.LPB.AAAGTAGGTCTAAAGA  N106.LPB.AACCATGGTACATGTC  
          CD4+ Activated                     Tregs              CD4+ Activated           CD4+ Activated
```

Using `as.factor(df1)` doesn't work - I want it to be in the format of `factor1`. This seems very simple, but unsure how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
factor(setNames(df$cell.subset.Cluster, df$barcode))
```

Reproducible data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  barcode = c(
    "N106.LPB.AAACCTGAGCAGACTG", "N106.LPB.AAAGATGTCAGATAAG", 
    "N106.LPB.AAAGTAGGTCTAAAGA", "N106.LPB.AACCATGGTACATGTC"
  ),
  `cell.subset.Cluster` = c("CD4+ Activated", "Tregs", "CD4+ Activated", "CD4+ Activated")
)
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry about not putting in reproducible data. Will accept your answer.